# Has anyone used bleak to connect multiple BLE devices and receive notifications from all of them simultaneously?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am able to use bleak and get data from all 5 BLE sensors. But the problem is that I am unable to identify which data is from which device. I mean i need a string representing the address of the device alongwith the data itself.

Comment: The [bleak example](https://github.com/hbldh/bleak/blob/develop/examples/two_devices.py) for two devices shows a callback that includes the notifications sender. Wouldn't that work for you?

Comment: SIr, i have already implemented it. I am able to connect 5 sensor modules with the example. But now the problem is that for handling the notifications I have a callback function. It gives the sender, and the data from server. Now, i want to distinguish which data is from which server. I mean while debugging the application, I want the device address to be displayed besides the data for every device.

Comment: Moreover, the sender is the characteristic handle. For me its 13. And I am printing that with every notification data i receive. I am having devices of same manufacturer. And i am only subscribing one characteristic, so sender remains 13 always.

Comment: Please suggest and update or edit in the function I can have to get better results.

Comment: I see, thank you for clarifying. I've seen that you also asked this question on [github](https://github.com/hbldh/bleak/issues/601). I hope you get an answer

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get data simultaneously from all the BLE modules using bleak in Windows, as well as on raspberry pi.

The only problem with Windows is that if you use Bluetooth 4.2 adapter & above. It will be much better for the high speed data rate, and proper devices connection handling. As with the 4.0 adapter, I have always gone through one or two exceptions each time i started the script, and the maximum number of connections I got was 3.

When i tried this script on Raspberry pi 3b+, it has on-board chip of Bluetooth 4.2. It was able to give high speed data rate, and my 5 sensors were connected to it simultaneously.

Also, The two_devices examples in bleak source code on Github, is very good example for starting with further coding.

And if you run the script and found the data on console, but you were unable to get that which data is from device. Then you need to use functools, (what it does is it will inject the client you're connected to at present, with the callback function, and it will make the work much easier).

Check this out on Github: https://github.com/hbldh/bleak/issues/601